# How to declare genericy key value pair array in java

Tags: java, generics

Hello friends i am new to java collection, i need to create an array as follows,

Array(
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":[
      "key21":"value21",
      "key22":"value22"
     ],
  "key3":"value3"
)

value's datatype's are specified dynamically. If example or tutorials available please share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to use a HashMap. Check this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm)

Comment: Any chance to adjust the data structure? Where do you get those data?

Comment: above link show's only value's with double data type's, may i use combination's such as double as value1, array in value2 and some other data type in succeeding value's is the above i have mentioned.

Comment: nitek, these are payload from post request.

Comment: Is it realy a dynamic structure then? Is the form (is it a form?) which sends the data that flexible?

Comment: You can create a HashMap<Integer, Object> or if more appropriate create a Class to store your values and use a HashMap<Integer, ClassName>

Comment: thank u nitek and anaxin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map is a key-value pair

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Object> map;
        map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        map.put(1,"any object");
        map.put(2,"fits here");
        map.put(3,5555555);
    }
```